# service scale limitations with ingress in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

To make ingress work [as far as I understand it](https://medium.com/google-cloud/understanding-kubernetes-networking-ingress-1bc341c84078) you need to create all services (that are using ingress controllers) as type NodePort.

Therefore is 2768 the service limit for ingress (maximum available NodePorts)?

Answer (score 1):

You're understanding isn't necessarily correct.

It depends on your environment, cloud provider, ingress controller etc. Because the ingress controller is provisioned inside the cluster, all services that requires an ingress can use ClusterIP, and the ingress controller will route traffic to it.

Again, depending on your platform, the only service that *needs* to be type=NodePort is the service attached to your ingress controller deployment. The rest can be ClusterIP

Comment: your logic makes sense to me and that is what I originally thought until I read the link in my question and lots of other examples online where applications are all deployed with service type NodePort with ingress controllers hence my confusion.